# LaunchUriAsync() doesn't launch Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm trying call my application on OnShareTargetActivated() method by LaunchUriAsync() but it doesn't work.

I have a protocol called "myapp" in appmanifest. When I put "myapp://test" on File Explorer, my application is launched, but when I do it:

```
protected async override void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
{
   Uri uri = new Uri("myapp://test");
   await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
}
```

This occurs when the user clicks on my application that is on Charm Bar in Share option. But the application is never launched.

Comment: Can you clarify - "doesn't work".  And so I'm clear - someone in another app (not yours) invokes Share, and picks your app.  Then you want to immediately launch a DIFFERENT app, the one with myapp:// protocol?  That seems odd, and I can see why we might not what that to happen, but not sure if it's strictly disallowed.

Comment: The user may be, for example, the Photos app, select some images and select my application to share on charm bar. What I want to do is literally open the application, as if I had clicked on your tile.

Comment: Did you try calling the launch on the UI Thread?

Answer (score 1):

sharing app sample (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Target-App-e2689782)

You should check the format , of what you are sharing , metro will only accept some type of content to share , Sharing format are  Text,uri,Bitmap,storageitems,Html

share target code and pictures (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/going_metro/archive/2012/05/03/integrating-with-windows-8-share-charm-part-1-receiving-data.aspx)

if u find useful , pls acccept as answer

Comment: I known use Share Target. I need open my application outside of Charm Bar like I have clicked on your Tile. I need do this 'cause for some reason a Windows Store App can't connect two devices by Wi-Fi Direct in Charm Bar.

Comment: can u connect in the main program ?